# Azure DevOps Build Pipeline - Multi-Project Solution with single NuGet.config

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

I am having a few issues getting an Azure DevOps single project build pipeline working properly in a multi-project solution. I have a solution with multiple projects within it, and I'm trying to get one project in an Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline. Below is a simplified version of what the solution looks like:

```
.nuget (folder with NuGet.config file)
SharedProject
WebProject1
WebProject2
WebProject3
Application.sln
```

All of the web projects use the shared project, and in addition to that, I have that .nuget folder in the base solution folder, with a .NuGet.config file that all of the projects in the solution use.

In my pipeline, if I have it setup to trigger a CI build off changes to $\TFVC\Application\WebProject1, when the build agent runs the checkout step is missing the entire solution's ".nuget" folder. The build agent sets up a workspace tied directly to the WebProject1 folder and then gets all of the code before it runs the nuget restore command, but since the .nuget folder is missing when the build agent gets the latest changeset, then the nuget restore fails because the NuGet.config file is missing.

Any idea on how I can setup an Azure DevOps CI pipeline monitoring a single project's folder in a solution to trigger the build, while also including the solution's ".nuget" folder as well. Ideally, the CI trigger would get hit when either the WebProject1 folder or SharedProject folder in the solution is updated (using path filters), but for now I'm just trying to get one project to work.

Or is there a way to setup a single .nuget/NuGet.config file for the solution, and there is a pointer in each WebProject to that file, that makes it appear as if it needs to be pulled when getting the latest in the CI build pipeline.

Comment: I know nuget, CI/CD, Azure Pipelines but I'm struggling to understand what is the problem you are trying to solve and what the issue is. Can you formulate the issue in one sentence, please?

Comment: @VladDX When I try to build a single project in a multi-project solution, the solution item NuGet.config in the .nuget folder isn't being included by the build agent when getting the code, so it fails to restore any nuget packages.

Comment: Can you post your `.gitignore` file? You might have something there that prevents `.nuget` getting to the repo. Can you show a screenshot of `.nuget` present in the repo with branch visible? Can you show the run of the pipeline with repo name and branch name visible?